# R language: how to clear the frames/stack in Rstudio/console

Tags: r, traceback

By stack, I refer to the output from traceback() upon error condition.
How does one 'clear the stack' so one gets 'No traceback available' from traceback()?
thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: A more standard thing would be to use `try` or `tryCatch` to control what happens when the error is thrown, rather than deal with `traceback`.

Comment: I misunderstood that non-NULL traceback output implied R maintained an operating stack (frame to be examined) in memory; it appears only package(debug) & options(error=recover) etc. do what I had assumed; in another word, when an error occurs with options(error=NULL), the state of the memory (frames with local variables) with error is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done by overwriting the `.Traceback` variable which is currently stored in the `base` namespace:

```
stop("Hammer Time!")
Error: Hammer Time!
traceback()
1: stop("Hammer Time!")
assign(".Traceback",NULL,"package:base")
traceback()
No traceback available
```

Be warned though:

> It is undocumented where .Traceback is stored nor that it is visible,
>   and this is subject to change.

Answer (score 0):

you could always do this

```
 getOption(showWarnCalls, FALSE)
 getOption(showErrorCalls, FALSE)
```